# Speeding up my cloudant query

Tags: node.js, couchdb, cloudant, database-tuning

I was wondering whether someone could provide some advice on my cloudant query below. It is now taking upwards of 20 seconds to execute against a DB of 50,000 documents - I suspect I could be getting better speed than this.

The purpose of the query is to find all of my documents with the attribute "searchCode" equalling a specific value plus a further list of specific IDs.

Both searchCode and _id are indexed - any ideas why my query would be taking so long / what I could do to speed it up?

```
mydb.find({selector: {"$or":[{"searchCode": searchCode},{"_id":{"$in":idList}}]}}, function (err, result) {
   if(!err){
      fulfill(result.docs);
   }
   else{
      console.error(err);
   }
});
```

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing separate calls for the queries

- find me documents where the searchCode = 'some value'
- find me documents whose ids match a list of ids

The first can be achieved with a `find` call and a query like so:

```
{ selector: {"searchCode": searchCode} }
```

The second can be achieved by hitting the databases's [_all_docs](https://docs.cloudant.com/database.html#get-documents) endpoint, passing in the list of ids as a `keys` parameter e.g.

```
GET /db/_all_docs?keys=["a","b","c"]
```

You might find that running both requests in parallel and merging the results gives you better performance.

Comment: Thanks Glynn - I have separated the two and it seems the problem I am having is with with ID part of the call - the query by searchcode returns almost immediately but the ID call is still taking over 15 seconds - ill investigate this further

Comment: Hi Glynn - I actually got this to work as you suggest using my modules .list method which must call GET/db/_all_docs however I'm now having an issue where the number of keys im passing in is exceeding the limit as a query parameter. Any ideas here? I've seen documentation suggesting you can retrieve all_docs with a POST on couch_db to submit a large quantity of keys - is this the same on cloudant?

Comment: I resolved this - thanks you were right running them as separate queries were much more efficient. I did end up following my suggesting of POSTing to /db/_all_docs with the keys in the body which worked for my large set of keys